# Node.js express validator validate req.body is not empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

Is there any elegant way to use express-validator to validate the req.body I got is not empty?

I didn't see any appropriate validator in here:
https://github.com/chriso/validator.js

And I prefer not to use (Object.keys(req.body).length == 0)

Is there any custom validator I should build to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like two questions to me, please consider editing this and posting your other question separately

Comment: No, you can't. Validator is used for string validation and sanitization. Object.keys is the most simple way with less memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For latter question **2. How to create a conditional validation (at least one of 'a','b','c' params is required).** Not tested but something like below should work:

```
var hasRequiredField = Object.keys(req.body).some(function(key) {
return ['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(key) >= 0;
});

if(hasRequiredField) {
} else {

}
```